# Multi-tenant database design

Tags: design, database-design, sql-server, multitenancy

My boss is currently working on a database design for a multi-tenant capable ERP/CRM system, which will have a Sql Server backend.

Some key points of the design:

- A server instance will host a "shared" database (unique model), plus one database per company (same model)
- The "shared" database have tables like contacts, users, etc. that will be referred to by other company databases.
- The "shared" database have triggers that will check if its data can safely be deleted (if it's used by any company, the DELETE operation must fail)
- If, for security concerns, a company must NOT use shareable information, it must be set up on its own server instance, with its own "shared" database that will, in fact, be used only by that company.

And here's an implementation example for a system:

SERVER INSTANCE 1:

- Shared DB
- ACME
- WayneEnterprises
- KwikEMart

SERVER INSTANCE 2:

- Shared DB
- Umbrella

My boss stands by this design on the following believed benefits:

- Since there's one db per company, smaller companies like KwikEMart won't suffer from the weight of the bigger ones.
- User access can be defined on a "per-company" strategy. This way, Apu can be granted the privilege to read KwikEMart's `Invoices` table, but not ACME's.

Although I understand these benefits, the integrity tradeoffs seems overwhelming to me.

First, there's the obvious integrity cut-off between companies db and the shared db. It's impossible to make foreign keys across db boundaries.

Second, what if the Joker messes up with WayneEnterprises database so bad that Batman will have to restore a day-old backup? If ACME, on that very same day, decided to remove a shared Gotham address that was still in use in the older WayneEnterprises db, then every document which used that address won't be able to display it anymore. Unless of course there's a shared db backup from the exact same time that can be restored. But EVEN if there was one, it could lead to even more problems for both ACME and KwikEMart.

And that's just the two issues that popped right into my mind, there's probably others as well.

So my question here would be: are we getting in the right direction with this? And also, how does this kind of system is normally built?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the shared DB?  Why not just have one self-contained database for each company?

Comment: Also, it's called "Multi-Tenant," if you want to research it.

Comment: Are the databases accessed directly by your customers?  To be honest I think he is making a tall assumption that a database with a complex schema is "always" slower than a smaller complexity database.  That is like saying that All C++ programs are faster and more efficient than all Java programs, which is also an unfair stereotype with many many variables that factor into it.  Honestly it sounds like you want to have a rich domain model that satisfies all customers and encapsulate your direct database access through web services.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The shared DB's purpose is to hold on data that would be used by multiple companies, like customer addresses, phone numbers, a list of countries, order statuses multilingual descriptions, etc, etc... for example, both ACME and Wayne Enterprises could be doing business with a customer named Stark Industries. If Stark were to change its business phone number or move out to another city, an attendant would only have one place to go to update that data, rather than going through every company that potentially does business with Stark.

Comment: You can make foreign keys across the database boundaries if you use GUIDs instead of INTs for the keys.

Comment: @maple_shaft I think the performance assumptions are more made around transaction volume and disk I/O. Of course, the fact that all dbs would still be on the same server almost eradicate that argument IMHO :). Although I think we'd still have the ability to split I/O activities across different harddisks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's true, and we do. However, there will be no integrity check in place to make sure that when an PO must be created for a customer, its ID is indeed valid and existing inside the shared database. Of course you can use INSTEAD OF triggers to check the validity but this comes with tradeoffs on its own and it won't change the fact that if the shared db gets restored to an older version, your recently-validated data might no longer be valid.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't store the addresses in two places, if that's what you mean.  Either store them in the shared database for everyone, or store them in the local databases and use the shared database as a "phone book."  The addresses in the local databases are the "official" version.

Comment: I've never seen the advantage of maintaining a separate database per customer like this.  All the multi-tenant systems I've worked on kept everything in a single database and used a customer/company id to logically keep the customers' data separate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not following here. How would storing the address in the local databases be "storing it in one place"?

Comment: @GrandmasterB How did you deal with backup / restore operations and security on these systems?

Comment: @Crono well, backups are no different.  We also offered an export if the customers wanted their data in a usable format (csv, excel, etc).  Restoration was never much of an issue.  We didn't delete most things, so if someone deleted a building, for example, we'd toggle the deletion flag for it.  There was also an import process typically used for bulk import from other systems, but could be used to restore a company's data in an emergency.

Comment: There has to be one canonical place for the addresses.  Either it's in the master database, or it's in the individual databases.  Whatever place you choose, that's where the canonical Primary Key for each address will be sourced.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Okay but if somebody had accidently deleted every orders for ONE tenant then you'd have to restore a backup for the full db, meaning *every* tenant would lose whatever they'd done since that last restoration point. Am I correct?

Comment: @Crono I would point you to at least two articles on the web that more throughly discuss the topic [Choosing a Multi-Tenant Data Architecture
](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534480.aspx) and [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

Comment: @Crono no, as I said we did not delete most things so all it would take is toggling the status of the order.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I understand that your software did not delete things, but Sql Server is still Sql Server. Someone with the appropriate permissions could still connect to it from outside your app and do whatever s/he wants, including deleting records. Even if you blocked delete actions in triggers, these can be deactivated. But I disgress. The point is that a single db with multiple tenants simply won't meet our requirements. That's one of the few things I'm pretty sure of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the multi tennent systems I have worked on as a DBA and Developer we used 1 database per client.  That database was completely self contained and did not rely on any shared database, not even for things like the states in the US.

To make standing up a new client easy a model database was created that had all the things like States prepopulated.

The reason we did not store addresses or other common data in a shared database is that it allowed us to move the databases around several different servers to normalize the load accross the servers we had.  If a database needed a higher SLA due to a client upgrade we could just take a backup and restore the client database on the appropriate server and not need to worry if "the address for Stark Industries" existed on the new server.

The obvious question is what happens when client A updates the phone number or address for a customer?  Should client B see that change?  Wouldn't that lead to "duplicated" data if every thing is stored in seperate databases?

What if "Stark Industries" wants your Client A using a different phone number than your Client B?  Then you will have to have a way to show that and store the different numbers in the Client database or move Client A and Client B to different instances.  I am sure as you look through your shared database you will find additional instances of this problem of different clients wanting to use data differently.

For updates to the common tables a script that loops through each database is rather easy to write, a cursor on sys.databases and some dynamic SQL takes care of that part.

Overall while having a shared database may look good from a normalization standpoint once you start to look at different ways that clients use the different data, a shared database may not make sense any more.  If you are going to go the route of seperate databases per client, just go full bore and go completely seperate with no shared data.

Comment: +1, shared-nothing designs are much simpler, and the reasons against them always seem to be premature optimization (or ethically-dubious aggregation of data).

Comment: Your "different phone" number is indeed a scenario that came up early in the analysis phase. My boss's solution for that was to allow multiple phone numbers for a customer, and a link table inside the tenant's databases. The shared db's role is basically to hold on to actual and undeniable facts, like "there *is* a state in the US called New Jersey", "that phone number exists no matter who owns it", "there *are* people doing business at that address", etc, etc. I do believe that's overkill but unfortunately I don't have enough experience to talk my boss out of it, which is why I asked here.

Comment: @Crono  While a common database would seem to make sense I have always found (as kdgregory stated) its premature optimazation.  The dificulties introduced in developing out weigh the benefits.  While yes there is a state in the US called New Jersey the extra space of a less than 1mb (mB?) table over a hundred databases is increadibly cheap compared to the extra time for development and testing.  a 1TB western digital Red (enterprise grade) runs about $65.  If it takes more than 1 hour of extra dev time it just cost the company money.

Comment: @WindRaven Of course space is not the concern here, it's much more about data synchronization. Out of sync data can cost a company money too. Granted, having "New Jersey" for tenant 1 and "New Ejrsey" for tenant 2 probably isn't *that* bad. What *could* be bad though, is sending a 20 000$ worth shipment of perishable material in the wrong state because a customer's address wasn't updated for every company db (although at this point there's probably just too much incompetent people in the processing chain :) ). In any case, that's the kind of thing my boss aims to eradicate.

Comment: @Crono It comes down to how much hand holding you want to do.  If you make your Clients responsible for having the correct address it is on your clients.  To turn your situation around, Client A changes the address for "Stark Industries" which causes Client B to send a 20K shipment to the wrong state for Stark Industries.  Who is responsible?  Client A for changing the address? Client B for not noticing? or Your company who designed the system that way? .....

Comment: I guess I am not seeing why your company would be responsible for making sure addresses are up to date.  To me it looks like a giant liability that you can very easily pass off to your clients.  Be a software company that produces a product (and provides as SaaS if that is the case).  As soon as you start trying to maintain a shared database it seems to open up at least the possibility of a lawsuit even if you would eventually win.